# Tkinter detect when OptionMenu selection has changed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Currently working on a Notepad application and having problems with the OptionMenu widget.

```
self.fileOptionMenu = OptionMenu(self.master, self.var, *self.fileList, command=self.openFileCurrentDir)
self.fileOptionMenu.pack()

def openFileCurrentDir(self):
    print("inside openFileCurrentDir()")
```

the `openFileCurrentDir()` function is never ran after changing the selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trace` method on your `StringVar`.

```
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    self.var = StringVar()
    self.var.trace("w", self.openFileCurrentDir)
    l = ["A","B","C","D"]
    self.fileOptionMenu = OptionMenu(self.master, self.var, *l)
    self.fileOptionMenu.pack()

def openFileCurrentDir(self,*args):
    print("inside openFileCurrentDir()"+self.var.get())
```